# Forwarding tuple<...> containing deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, tuples, move, variadic-functions, perfect-forwarding

I have a function wrapper for use over the network:

```
#pragma once

#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

struct ZPackage {
    std::unique_ptr<int> m_dummy;

    template<typename T>
    T Read() {
        T t = T();
        return t;
    }
};

class ZRpc;

template <class C, class Tuple, class F, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto invoke_tuple_impl(F f, C& c, ZRpc* rpc, Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::invoke(f, c, rpc, std::move(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}

template <class C, class Tuple, class F>
constexpr void invoke_tuple(F f, C& c, ZRpc* rpc, Tuple t) {
    invoke_tuple_impl(f, c, rpc, std::move(t),
        std::make_index_sequence < std::tuple_size<Tuple>{} > {}); // last arg is for template only
}

class ZRpcMethodBase
{
public:
    virtual void Invoke(ZRpc* pao, ZPackage& pkg) = 0;
};

template<class C, class...Args>
class ZRpcMethod final : public ZRpcMethodBase {
    using Lambda = void(C::*)(ZRpc*, Args...);

    C* object;
    Lambda lambda;

    template<class F>
    auto Invoke_impl(ZPackage& pkg) {
        return std::tuple(pkg.Read<F>());
    }

    // Split a param,
    // Add that param from Packet into tuple
    template<class F, class S, class...R>
    auto Invoke_impl(ZPackage& pkg) {
        auto a(Invoke_impl(pkg));
        std::tuple<S, R...> b = Invoke_impl<S, R...>(pkg);
        return std::tuple_cat(a, b);
    }

public:
    ZRpcMethod(C* object, Lambda lam) : object(object), lambda(lam) {}

    void Invoke(ZRpc* rpc, ZPackage& pkg) override {
        // Invoke_impl returns a tuple of types by recursion
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Args))
        {
            auto tupl = Invoke_impl<Args...>(pkg);

            invoke_tuple(lambda, object, rpc, tupl);
        }
        else
        {
            // works like ~magic~
            std::invoke(lambda, object, rpc);
        }
    }
};
```

I have added in some of the types that are utilized, `ZRpc`, `ZPackage`, and an example `Object`.

I am struggling with getting this wrapper to work with types that have a deleted copy constructor, such as `std::unique_ptr` (or in this example the `ZPackage` which contains the `std::unique_ptr`. The specific error I get:

> std::tuple::tuple(const std::tuple &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

```
#include "TestRpc.h"

class ZRpc { };

struct Object {
    void ok_method(ZRpc* rpc, int i) {

    }

    void broken_method(ZRpc* rpc, ZPackage pkg) {

    }
};

int main() {
    ZRpc rpc;
    Object obj;

    // compiles fine
    auto a = new ZRpcMethod(&obj, &Object::ok_method);

    // does not compile
    auto b = new ZRpcMethod(&obj, &Object::broken_method);

}
```

I doubt that it will make a difference, but just for reference, here are some things I have tried and commented out previously with no avail: https://pastebin.com/aHSsLzWe. I am unable to wrap my head around variadic templates and how to correctly forward.

How can I achieve perfect forwarding with move-only constructor types?

EDIT:
I changed the std::forward to move

Comment: You probably don't need perfect forwarding here, given that arguments always come from deserializing stuff. I'd just `std::move()` the result of `std::get()`. Also `std::forward<Tuple>(t)` is wrong, in the sense that it'll always act as `std::move`. If that's what you intended, better spell it as `std::move`.

Comment: It finally actually compiled for once. Ill run tests to check if it works as expected, but thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong. I forgot to uncomment the test for the ZPackage. I made edits above reflecting your recommended changes. I'm still getting the error reference to the deleted function.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Invoke()` function body, since `if constexpr (sizeof...(Args)) == 1` is true, this will invoke `Invoke_impl<Args...>(pkg)` which will return a `std::tuple<ZPackage>` which is move-only, so you also need to `std::move` it into `invoke_tuple()`.

```
if constexpr (sizeof...(Args)) {
  auto tupl = Invoke_impl<Args...>(pkg);
  invoke_tuple(lambda, object, rpc, std::move(tupl));
} else {
  // ...
}
```